# The overriding of anonymous internal class methods does not work

Tags: java, overriding

Can you override a method in this way?

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {        
        File dir = new File("M:\\Java\\Test") {
            @Override
            public String[] list() { 
                String[] listA = super.list();                
                for (String s : listA) {
                    s = "test" + s;
                }                
                return listA;
            }
        };
        String[] listB = dir.list();
        for (String s : listB) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected:

```java
test1.txt
test10.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
test4.txt
test5.txt
test6.txt
test7.txt
test8.txt
test9.txt
```

I received:

```java
1.txt
10.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt
7.txt
8.txt
9.txt
```

I can't ask a new question and it concerns the same code so I will ask here. Is a compiler error caused by nesting method overrides?

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File("M:\\Java\\Test") {
            @Override
            public String[] list() {
                String[] listA = super.list(new FilenameFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File file, String string) {
                        return string.contains(".txt");
                    }
                });
                for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
                    listA[i] = "test" + listA[i];
                }                                
                return listA;
            }
        };
        String[] listB = dir.list();
        for (String s : listB) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I recived:

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)  
        at findmyorder.test$1.list(test.java:22)  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)  
        at findmyorder.test$1.list(test.java:22)  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)  
        at findmyorder.test$1.list(test.java:22)  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)  
        at findmyorder.test$1.list(test.java:22)  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)  
        at findmyorder.test$1.list(test.java:22)  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)  
        at findmyorder.test$1.list(test.java:22)  
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)
```

It looks like some infinite loop. The problem arose after adding `FilenameFilter` to the `list()` function.
Is this the result of nested `@Override`?

Comment: You're changing the iteration variable `s` not the values of array `listA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
String[] listA = super.list();                
for (String s : listA) {
   s = "test" + s;
}
```

You create a **new** string object, and assign that to a reference that **formerly** pointed to a member of your array.

Then:

```
 return listA;
```

you return that array.

Your code does **not** change the content of the array. You iterate the array, create a new string for each entry. Then you throw that new string away, to then return the original, unmodified array.

You could a one liner like:

```
return Arrays.stream(super.list()).map(s -> s = "test" + s).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Besides that, I would be really careful about using polymorphism like that. The contract of the File says: this method returns the "child file" names. The contract doesn't say: it returns manipulated file names. So, for real, production code usage, I would rather create a helper/utilities class that implements its "own" contract, that says: "give me a list of files, and I prepend them in a meaningful way with a prefix".

Comment: String[] listB = dir.list();
        for (String s : listB) {
            s = "test" + s;
            System.out.println(s);

So why does this code work?

Comment: Excuse me. I am a new forum user. I don't know the convention. I will remember about this.

Comment: @kAEm It wasn't necessary to change the accept though. Anyway: I am glad that you got answers to your question quickly!

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the same list. Replace your for loop with this:

```
        for(int i=0;i<listA.length;i++)
        {
            listA[i] = "test" + listA[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this line:

```
s = "test" + s;
```

All that does is update the `s` variable. It has no effect whatsoever on the string in the list.

Instead, build a new array with the updated names, and return that.

```
@Override
public String[] list() { 
    String[] listA = super.list();                
    String[] listB = new String[listA.length]; // ***
    int n = 0;                                 // ***
    for (String s : listA) {
        listB[n++] = "test" + s;               // ***
    }                
    return listB;                              // ***
}
```

---

Side note: [`File#list`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#list()) can return `null`:

> **Returns:**
>
> An array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns `null` if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.**

*(my emphasis)*

...so you'll want to handle that possibility:

```
@Override
public String[] list() { 
    String[] listA = super.list();                
    if (listA == null) {                       // ***
        return null;                           // ***
    }                                          // ***
    String[] listB = new String[listA.length];
    int n = 0;
    for (String s : listA) {
        listB[n++] = "test" + s;
    }                
    return listB;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't update `listA` like [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805224/157247) I now see Shubhendu posted. No good reason, really; that would probably be better since the `File` class is handing over the array for use by the caller, it won't be keeping it for its own purposes...

Answer (score 0):

This

```
String[] listA = super.list();                
for (String s : listA) {
  s = "test" + s;
}                
return listA;
```

does not do what you expect. Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
  listA[i] = "test" + listA[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is an immutable class, so `s = "test" + s;` has no affect here. You should use something like this:

```
File dir = new File(".") {
  @Override
  public String[] list() {
    String[] listA = super.list();
    if (listA != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
        listA[i] = "test" + listA[i];
      }
    }
    return listA;
  }
};
String[] listB = dir.list();
if (listB != null) {
  for (String s : listB) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```